# Cleanup shared memory with vector inside

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost-interprocess

I'm using **boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory** to share some data between different processes and was wondering how cleanup works. In general, I have to following situation:

```
boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory *sharedSegment;
typedef boost::interprocess::allocator< MyObject, boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>  SharedMemoryAlloc;
typedef boost::interprocess::vector<MyObject, SharedMemoryAlloc> SharedVector;
SharedVector *sVec;
unsigned int size;

// Do some other stuff and determine correct size
sharedSegment= new boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory(boost::interprocess::create_only, "TEST", size);
SharedMemoryAlloc *allocToSharedSegment = new SharedMemoryAlloc(sharedSegment->get_segment_manager());
sVec = sharedSegment->construct<SharedVector>("MyVector")( (*allocToSharedSegment) );
delete allocToSharedSegment; 

// Fill sVec, do some computation etc..

// Start cleanup
//sVec->clear(); 
delete sharedSegment;

boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove("TEST");
```

Since I call boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove("TEST"); I always thought, that everything inside the memory is deleted anyway, and therefore I do not have to take care of sVec. But Visual Leak Detector told me, there were some memory leaks at this point. If I clear the vector before deleting the shared memory, everything works fine. 
Could it be, that sVec holds pointer internally and therefore I have to call clear()?

Comment: `valgrind` sees no leaks here. 6 blocks allocated, 6 blocks freed.

Comment: If you do call `clear()`, does the tool then report no errors?

Comment: Calling `clear()` fixes the problem. Maybe I should add, that `MyObject` contains another `std::vector` (I know, that this can be problematic, since the shared memory does not grow, if I the vector inside `MyObject` grows. But my code ensures, that there is enough space, if I add something to the vectors inside `MyObject`)

Comment: "MyObject contains another std::vector" — I can see a problem here. Make it `boost::interprocess::vector`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the hint. Is there a way to create a `boost::interprocess::vector`without using pointers or `new`? I just tried to use `SharedVector vec`, but there does not seem to be a standard c'tor for `boost::interprocess::vector`. Since the use of pointers imply dynamic allocation, I'm not sure if I can access the objects (since only the pointers to objects would be stored into shared memory, not the objects itself)

Comment: I don't think you can store (user-visible) pointers in shared memory.

Comment: @n.m. yes you can, but they must be of type `boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<>`